# How to extract link under a <li> tag with a specific class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<li class="a-last"><a href="/macbook-pro">Buy Now</a></li>
```

How can you extract the link `/macbook-pro` inside the class `a-last`? Efficiency is a consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is CSS selectors:

```
data = '''<li class="a-last"><a href="/macbook-pro">Buy Now</a></li>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('li.a-last [href]')['href'])
```

Prints:

```
/macbook-pro
```

---

`li.a-last [href]` will select tag with attribute `href` that is under `<li>` tag with class `a-last`.

If you want to be more specific and want to extract only `<a>` tag *directly* under `<li class="a-last">`, you can use:

```
print(soup.select_one('li.a-last > a[href]')['href'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<li class="a-last"><a href="/macbook-pro">Buy Now</a></li>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

href = soup.find('li', {'class': 'a-last'}).find('a').get('href')

print(href)
```

**RESULTS:**

```
/macbook-pro
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the list of all needed hrefs:

`[el.find('a').get('href') for el in soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'a-last'})]`